# Enabling logs in Spring boot cloud foundry application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, cloud-foundry, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-connectors

how do i enable spring framework logs in my application. ? i have used logback.xml in my application and set the root level to debug. When i am trying to run the app locally then logs are printed but the same is not happening when i am deploying the application in CF.
The application itself is crashing due to other reason but i hoped some initial spring boot framework logging should have happened.

Below is my logback.xml file. I am not sure the console appender mentioned there will work in CF system too or not.`

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
            <Pattern>
                %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
            </Pattern>
        </layout>
    </appender> 

<root level="TRACE">
<appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Best Regards,

Saurav

Comment: FYI, you don't need `logback.xml` to configure log levels with Spring Boot.  Delete that file and just add `logging.level.<package>` to your `application.properties` file.  Ex:  `logging.level.org.springframework=DEBUG` would set the log level for all of Spring to DEBUG.  See docs for more details:  https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-logging.html#howto-logging

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be this was a problem with the spring boot CF service broker application which was causing the logs to not be printed. Check here [CF Spring boot app failed to start accepting connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44652549/cf-spring-boot-app-failed-to-start-accepting-connections)

But then i deleted the application and redeployed again. It started printing logs. The above configuration works.

Comment: It sounds like your CF platform may be having issues.  Just a wild guess, but it could be a problem with the Cell where your app is running, thus when you delete the app, push it again and it lands on a new Cell you get logs.  If this happens again, my suggestion would be to start by pulling the logs from the Cell where your application is running and starting your investigation there.

Answer (score -1):

The above Logback configuration file should work.  Note: `TRACE` level logging will produce a lot of log messages.  It might be better to turn this down to `INFO`.  You'll need to bundle this configuration file in `src\main\resources\logback.xml` in your Spring Boot app structure.

Application logs in PCF [must be written to stdout or stderr](https://docs.pivotal.io/pivotalcf/1-6/devguide/deploy-apps/streaming-logs.html#writing) by your app, and you can view them in the CLI using the command `cf logs`.  The `ConsoleAppender` you're using above writes to stdout, so you should be good to go.

Comment: thanks for the reply...yes my xml file is under the resources folder...my only doubt was about the ConsoleAppender but if you say that is also fine...then i am at loss on why it is not working :)